# Why does html,body {height 100%} affect both width and height, but width 100% only affects width?

Tags: html, css

Given the following code, why does `html,body {height:100%}` allows the image to be responsive (allows measurements of its children to be written in percentage + works) at both height and width properties, but `html, body{width:100%}` only allows width to be responsive? If you could go in bit of detail how the browser treats width/height:auto (which I believe is the default value if nothing is selected), that would be great!

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/dafejayasi/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
 <style>

    html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }

  .image{
  height:40%;
  width:50%;
  }
  </style> 
<body>
  <img class = "image" src="http://www.placehold.it/700x300" alt="Image of storefront">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

by doing body's or html's width 100% or height 100% or both in together does not effect on anything on the body in this case !

Now given code will give you a brief understanding about how percentage works in browser

```
 .image{
        width:100%;
        //height not mention! 
}
```

in this case browser will select the height auto , that means the actual height of the image. when only if width change then height will change according to the the width. if width goes bigger height will goes bigger . nothing matters if only height changes

```
.image{
        height:100%;
        //width not mention
       }
```

now exact opposite case will be happen of above !

```
.image{
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
         }
```

here if width changes it will not effect on height and vice versa !
thanks!